# Picture claim not available when returning to ExternalCallback

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm in the process of upgrading two asp.net core 1.1 identityserver applications to asp.net core 2.

The first one, IdentityServer A is acting as a federated gateway and identity store. The second one, IdentityServer B is using A as external provider. In my app domain, clients should authenticate against B which puts additional claims on the identity which is received from A.

The authentication flow seems to be working fine at this point, except when B is adding additional claims to the identity.

On A the IdentityServer is configured as follows:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.GetClients())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityResources.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

The ProfileService on A is implemented like so:

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

    // Scope: OpenId
    AddClaimIfRequested(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, context.RequestedClaimTypes, context.IssuedClaims, user.Id);

    // Scope: Profile
    AddClaimIfRequested(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, context.RequestedClaimTypes, context.IssuedClaims, user.Firstname);
    AddClaimIfRequested(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, context.RequestedClaimTypes, context.IssuedClaims, user.Lastname);
    AddClaimIfRequested(JwtClaimTypes.Picture, context.RequestedClaimTypes, context.IssuedClaims, Convert.ToBase64String(user.ProfilePicture));

    // Scope: Email
    AddClaimIfRequested(JwtClaimTypes.Email, context.RequestedClaimTypes, context.IssuedClaims, user.Email);
}

private void AddClaimIfRequested(string claim, IEnumerable<string> requestedClaims, List<Claim> issuedClaims, string value)
{
    if (requestedClaims.Contains(claim))
        issuedClaims.Add(new Claim(claim, value));
}
```

On B the ExternalCallback from A is handled in the AccountController.ExternalCallback:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    //Read external identity from the tempoary cookie
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    if (result == null)
        throw new Exception("External authentication error");

    var externalUser = result.Principal;
    if (externalUser == null)
        throw new Exception("External authentication error");

    //Get external claims
    var claims = externalUser.Claims.ToList();

    ... additional identity handling and signin on B.
```

At this point, claims contains no picture claim. The other profile related claims that has been set in the ProfileService of A are all present. If I hardcode some other claim values in the ProfileService I see the values reflected in ExternalCallback as expected. But the picture claim isn't there. Furthermore the context.RequestedClaimTypes does contain "profile" when GetProfileDataAsync is being executed.

I've tried providing a hardcoded value for the picture claim (an url pointing to a png file (which seems to be the right way of doing it)), but no difference.
Since the picture value is a base64 encoded image file, I've also tried to increase the MaxResponseBufferSize for Kestrel, but that didn't make any difference either.

Since the claim values are being set in the ProfileService I guess it must be somewhere before the call to

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

Why the picture claim isn't there I can't figure out. Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**
Futher info. On B where .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc"... are defined, I've tried adding the OnUserInformationReceived event to options.Events. When the user information is received I can see the picture property as part of the User object on the context. So the information is available, but doesn't get added as a claim... it seems.